# Visual Studio 2012 exception error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have an animation gif on one of my xaml file.  When I go to design mode, I get following error:

```
IOException: Cannot locate resource 'resources/images/siren.gif'.

 at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream  stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder..ctor(Uri bitmapUri, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid expectedClsId)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapDecoder..ctor(Uri bitmapUri, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption)
   at Anubis.Controls.GifImage.SetupGifImage(Uri uri)
   at Anubis.Controls.GifImage.GifURIChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ev)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)

InnerException:  None
```

It seems like Visual Studio doesn't like to render the gif in VS2012.  I didn't get this error when using VS2010.  An explanation?

thanks
nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took out the animate gif and put static gif.  VS2012 seems to have issues for some reason with animated gif.